# TeamCity Visual Studio Tests build step to run single test

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, teamcity, visual-studio-test-runner

I have a Visual Studio solution with test projects , for example :

```
MySolution.sln
MyProject.csproj
MyProject.Tests.csproj
```

In TeamCity it's easy to create a build step of type `Visual Studio Tests` that targets all tests found in `MyProject.Tests.dll` ( those notated with `[TestMethod]` and `[DataTestMethod]` ).

I've done some Googling but I'm not finding how to run only a specific test by name - similar to Visual Studio right-click on test name and run tests.

Does anyone know if this is possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TeamCity uses VSTest.Console.exe under the hood to run tests. So basically, you can use params listed in here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/vstest-console-options?view=vs-2017, to decide, which tests should be run.

In TeamCity interface, there is a field `Test Names`. Use this field to specify tests to run:

[image: TeamCity Test Configuration]

This will give you something like this:

```
vstest.console.exe path\to\tests.assembly.dll /Tests:TestClass.TestName1,TestClass.TestName2
```

Comment: My `VSTest 2017` build-step UI does not have anything below `Test file names` in your screenshot. What version of `TeamCity Server` are you running ?

Comment: TeamCity 2018.2.1 (build 61078). By default this option might be hidden. Click `Show advanced options` on your build step. Here is link do documentation: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD18/Visual+Studio+Tests#VisualStudioTests-VSTestSettings